# Teshuva without kaballah le'asid

Tags: sources-mekorot, repentance-teshuvah

Is there a source for the idea that for a minimal level of repentance, it is enough for me to feel regret over sinning even though I know that I will return to the sin when the opportunity avails itself?

Comment: Why do you suspect there is a source for this idea? Did you make up the idea? Did you hear it somewhere? Where? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The *Mabit* in *Beit Elokim* (Shaar Teshuvah chapter 12) writes that each component of repentance accomplishes something regardless of fulfillment of the other components. He contrasts it to the *mitzvah* of *Tzitzit* where nothing is accomplished until all four corners of the garment have *Tzitzit*; you can't fulfill 3/4 of the *mitzvah* by having *Tzitzit* on 3 corners.